# cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '('

Tags: java, antlr4

I've broken up my combined grammar in two Lexer and Parser grammars:

The combined grammar is so easy like:

```
parser grammar Fluent;

fluent
 : MANDATORY
 | PARAMETRIZED '(' PARAMETER ')'
 | OPTIONS OPTION?
 | CHOOCING ( CHOOSE1 | CHOOSE2 )
 | PLUS+
 ;

MANDATORY : 'mandatory';
PARAMETRIZED : 'parameterized';
PARAMETER : 'parameter';
OPTIONS : 'options';
OPTION : 'option';
CHOOCING : 'choosing';
CHOOSE1: 'choise1';
CHOOSE2: 'choise2';
PLUS: 'plus';
```

Then I've created a `FluentLexer.g4` with lexer rules and a `FluentParser.g4` with parser rules.

Then I've imported `FluentLexer` grammar on `FluentParser` grammar.

I've tried two options:

- With an import FluentLexer in Fluent Grammar: `import FluentLexer`
- With an options structure:

  `options{
      language = Java;
      tokenVocab = FluentLexer;
  }`

Using the first one option ANTLR dumps me:

> cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '('
>
> error(126): FluentParser.g4:7:30: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ')'
>
> error(126): FluentParser.g4:3:12: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: 'mandatory'
>
> error(126): FluentParser.g4:4:15: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: 'parameterized'
>
> error(126): FluentParser.g4:5:12: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: 'parameter'
>
> ...

It seems Lexer rules are imported.

with the second one option, ANTLR tells me only:

> error(126): FluentParser.g4:10:16: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '('
>
> error(126): FluentParser.g4:10:30: cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: ')'

Why do I need to define ')' and '(' in separated grammars, and why don't I need to define them on a combined grammar?

How could I solve that? I want to use `'(' or ')'` insted of a LEXER rule...

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature only available for combined grammars. Probably to help speed up development/prototyping. However, it's "better" to user lexer rules instead. See: this Q&A: [Is "Implicit token definition in parser rule" something to worry about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102540/is-implicit-token-definition-in-parser-rule-something-to-worry-about)

> How could I solve that? I want to use '(' or ')' insted of a LEXER rule...

You can't in your case of separate grammars.